# What's the difference between BREAKING_WHITESPACE and WHITESPACE in Guava CharMatcher

Tags: java, whitespace, guava

In guava CharMatcher there are 2 inner class BREAKING_WHITESPACE and WHITESPACE, and the definition of BREAKING_WHITESPACE is : a whitespace which can be interpreted as a break between words for formatting purposes

What does it mean?

Can anyone answer this question ?

If you can provide an example for the diff it would be nice

Thx in advance

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is fairly general character stuff, not Guava specific:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space#Non-breaking_behavior
Actually the Javadoc says it all:

*Determines whether a character is a breaking whitespace (that is, a whitespace which can be interpreted as a break between words for formatting purposes).*

You put a non-breaking space in text between two words which must stay on the same line. Often it gets used for numbers with units like `123.456 MPa`. In HTML you'd write `&nbsp;`, ever seen it?

Out of [all whitespace chars](http://unicode.org/cldr/utility/list-unicodeset.jsp?a=%5Cp%7Bwhitespace%7D), there are some non-breaking, e.g. [U+0202F](http://www.charbase.com/202f-unicode-narrow-no-break-space) and [U+000A0](http://www.charbase.com/00a0-unicode-no-break-space).